# Firing an event everytime a new method is called

Tags: c#, events, clr

I am making a **logger** for a **c#** application which needs to log the time when each method was called each method's execution time.

I can do this by calling my own `EventLogger.LogMethodCall` method at the start of every method, but I was wondering if there was a way to make the **CLR** fire an event every time a new method is called so I wouldn't have to manually call my method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look into [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) and Aspect Oriented Programming

Comment: I also need an introduction to AOP so I think that I will go with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use a profiler to get the information you need?

Comment: How Petkovsky describes it, it definitely sounds more like profiler than logger.

Comment: It is an assignment so I have to make it myself basically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that can be done. Rather than write your own logger, may I recommend Log4Net?